# Indexer catalogrule_rule is set to invalid and causes the cache to be flushed a lot

Tags: cache, full-page-cache, indexer, magento2-cloud, mirasvit

I'm having a slowness issue on my client cloud instance.

Indexer catalogrule_rule is set to invalid and flush the caches a lot so the site is always slow even when we have the Miravit cache warmer extension installed.

Has anyone had any insight on what might cause it?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the indexer by running this command 
bin/magento indexer:reset  and then try to run indexer again

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this would cause the cache to be flushed again and I don't want that. I want to track down why the indexer was set to invalid and run via the cron a lot of time.